# What is the best session store for expressjs to store sessions on a mongodb (mongoose) database?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am developing an application with Express. I am using memory to store sessions at the moment. However, I would like to store them in mongodb.

I know I can just develop a store (it's just 5 functions). However, I was wondering: is there a good library to do that? I installed connect-mongodb, but apart from the fact that it has ancient versions of connect, bson, mongodb etc. as dependencies... I was wondering what the "current" established way to do this was.

I just found connect-mongo too (just to add to the mix).

Hints?

Merc.

Comment: You do not wish to use redis?

Comment: Everybody's talking about it, but I'd rather not have yet another thing running on the server, since mongodb is a fine storage engine etc. (but, maybe I am wrong?)

Comment: When you have bigger architecture with multiple server it make more sense to use the best tool for the job. When everything is running on the same machin using one one storage mechanism makes more sense. But why storing them in a cache/db then ? in memory should be good enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I touched on this in an answer to your other question, but older versions of dependencies don't necessarily mean a module is broken; if the module works with your version of MongoDB and has its own tests that pass, it's very likely it's fine (though it is sometimes worth determining if old versions of modules it depends on had dangerous bugs).

If you decide you don't want to use the module due to the outdated dependencies, you might also look into other modules that are more up to date; at a glance, [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb) might be a candidate.

Comment: Also, if it makes you feel any better, I use `connect-mongo` on http://nodecasts.net/, although that's by no indication the module is perfect--only that it works. :)

Comment: We've used connect-mongo with no problems; though obviously Brandon's caveats are applicable and wise to heed here too.